# Generic array printer not working for doubles type

Tags: c

I'm honestly going nuts here trying to understand why this generic array printer implementation is not working. Well, it works for an array of int's, but not for double's. What am I missing here?

```
void array_printer(FILE* stream, void* data, size_t data_type_size, size_t nr_rows, size_t nr_cols, char *format){

    size_t offset = 0;
    for (size_t r=0; r<nr_rows;++r){
        for (size_t c=0; c<nr_cols; ++c){
            fprintf(stream,format, *((int8_t*)data + offset*data_type_size));
            //fprintf(stream,format, *((char*)data + offset*data_type_size));  // same behaviour
            offset++;
        }
        fprintf(stream,"\n");
    }
}

void array_print_double_2D(FILE* stream, double* data, size_t nr_rows, size_t nr_cols){
    array_printer(stream, data, sizeof(double), nr_rows, nr_cols, " %lf ");
}

void array_print_int_2D(FILE* stream, int* data, size_t nr_rows, size_t nr_cols){
    array_printer(stream, data, sizeof(int), nr_rows, nr_cols, " %d ");
}

int main(){
    double *data_double = calloc(12, sizeof(double));
    data_double[0] = 1;
    data_double[1] = 2;
    data_double[2] = 3; 
    array_print_double_2D(stdout, data_double, 3, 4);
    /*
    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000         what??
    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
    */


    int*data_int = calloc(12, sizeof(int));
    data_int[0] = 1;
    data_int[1] = 2;
    data_int[2] = 3; 
    array_print_int_2D(stdout, data_int, 3, 4);
    /*
    1  2  3  0
    0  0  0  0               correct
    0  0  0  0
    */
```

Comment: `*(int8_t*)(data+...)`*will* return `int8_t` which is not consistent with printf specifier " %lf "

Comment: Try bigger integer values that don't fit into unto `int8_t`, e.g. 256.

Comment: Moreover, declaration ` double *data_int` is a bit confusing.

Comment: is your second example supposed to say `int *data_int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression `*(int8_t*)(data+...)` *will* return int8_t which is not consistent with printf specifier " %lf ". This results in Undefined behavior.

The problem can be efficiently solved with macros that generate the printers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define DEFINE_ARRAY_PRINT_2D(TYPE, FMT) \
void array_print_ ## TYPE ## _2D(FILE* stream, void* data, size_t nr_rows, size_t nr_cols) { \
    size_t offset = 0; \
    for (size_t r=0; r<nr_rows;++r){ \
        for (size_t c=0; c<nr_cols; ++c){ \
            fprintf(stream,FMT, ((TYPE*)data)[offset]); \
            offset++; \
        } \
        fprintf(stream,"\n"); \
    } \
}

// generate printers
DEFINE_ARRAY_PRINT_2D(int, " %d ")
DEFINE_ARRAY_PRINT_2D(double, " %lf ")


int main(){
    double *data_double = calloc(12, sizeof(double));
    data_double[0] = 1;
    data_double[1] = 2;
    data_double[2] = 3; 
    array_print_double_2D(stdout, data_double, 3, 4);

    int *data_int = calloc(12, sizeof(int));
    data_int[0] = 1;
    data_int[1] = 2;
    data_int[2] = 3; 
    array_print_int_2D(stdout, data_int, 3, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Produces output:

```
 1.000000  2.000000  3.000000  0.000000 
 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 
 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 
 1  2  3  0 
 0  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  0
```

As expected.

Answer (score 1):

You're casting the memory to `int8_t*` and dereferencing it, what were you expecting? I'd provide some sort of enumeration to distinguish between the typesand cast to the right one when needed.